# how can before and after inherit color from parent via tag attribute

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and sass. So I have an html tag with a color set via the span tag like so...

```
<div class="non-semantic-protector">    
   <span class="badge badge-primary">testing</span>
</div
```

In my sass, how do I make it so when a person changes the color for the tag from within the html (badge-primary to badge-danger for example), my :before and :after use the same color entered in via the  tag?

Here is my sass code...

```
.non-semantic-protector { position: relative; z-index: 1; }

span.badge {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

span.badge {
  &:after, &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  &:after, &:before {
    top: 0em;
    right: -1em;
    border-width: 1em 1em 1em 3em;
    border-color: currentColor transparent currentColor currentColor;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

I am trying to use currentColor but all I get is white instead of bootstrap blue. How can I make it so the user can use a bootstrap color and my after and before automatically pick that color up?

Comment: You could override the bootstrap's `badge-variant` mixin adding for example `border-color: $bg transparent $bg $bg;` and then using `border-color:inherit;` to your `&::after, &::before` rules. I did not test it, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor), `currentColor` is the value of the `color` property.

In Bootstrap 4, the styles for the `badge-primary` class are:

```
.badge-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

So correctly, in this context, `currentColor` equals to `#fff` which is the given color value for this element.

Unfortunately you won't get the Bootstrap blue color for free unless you specifically ask for something like this in your `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements:

```
.badge-primary::before {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```